# PHP: Does this whitelist on file_get_contents() prevent injection attacks?

Tags: php, security, file-get-contents

If I have 2 sites:

- a storage site storing my images (myStorageSite.com/images/),
- a main site (mainSite.com).

I want the user to supply a filename ($file) to get any file in the images directory of myStorageSite.com.  (the user knows the filenames).

Does this "whitelist" code let the user get any file from the images directory but prevent them from getting any other files on either myStorageSite or mainSite?

```
<?php

function dataURL($file, $mime){
  $white = 'http://myStorageSite.com/images/';
  $contents = file_get_contents($white . $file);
  $base64   = base64_encode($contents); 
  return ('data:' . $mime . ';base64,' . $base64);
}

?>
```

Suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't whitelisting. Whitelisting is comparing `$file` to a "list" of allowed filenames. And to answer your question, no, what you're doing allows them to get any file available on the storage server, try passing "../" as `$file` for example.

Whitelisting, if properly implemented, *would* do what you want though.

Comment: +1 owed to you when I gain the rep! Thanks! I think I understand...malicious users can just walk upward from the images directory with ../.  So a proper whitelist would need to be checking $file as an exact match against an array of full path+filenames.  Do you know of a regex (or other test) on $file that would stop malicious users from escaping the images directory?

Comment: Stripping out "../" could help, removing any characters that aren't allowed in filenames should help as well.

Answer (score 1):

## Simply put: Not exactly.

It will prevent people from accessing your data on mainSite.com, but **it will not** restrict people to the images folder.  Someone could do this:

```
$file = '../whatever_folder_on_mystorage_site';
```

All you are doing, is prepending the url to access with `file_get_contents`.

Since you are retrieving images, you can use actaully whitelist certain extensions.  Only allow the user to access certain extensions like .jpg, .png, and the like...

Comment: +1 owed to you when I gain the rep! Thanks, I understand better now.  I was hoping for a more generic whitelist.  Do you know of a regex (or other test) on $file that would stop malicious users from escaping the images directory?